# Did Tahiri have sex with Jacen Solo?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-motivation

Shortly before the Legends canon ended, [**Tahiri Veila**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tahiri_Veila) was put on trial for her time as Jacen Solo's - er, Darth Caedus' - apprentice, and specifically for the murder of Gilad Pellaeon. During the trial, when she is being questioned by the prosecutor, we have the following exchange:

> [...] "please tell the court about your… relationship with Jacen
>   Solo?"
>
> Now he was going in for the kill. He could switch gears fast. She'd
>   half expected Eramuth to leap forward with an objection, but he seemed
>   completely at ease.
>
> "Of course," she said, taking her cue from her lawyer and not rising
>   to the bait. "I knew Jacen Solo half my life."
>
> "So there was no personal relationship?"
>
> She'd known this was coming, and replied calmly. "There was."
>
> He tried and failed to hide the gleam of excitement in his eyes.
>   "Please elaborate on the nature of this relationship."
>
> "Objection," said Eramuth. "Surely, the court has no prurient interest
>   in the details of Tahiri Veila's private life."
>
> "Your Honor, I am trying to establish how deeply involved the accused
>   and Jacen Solo were, whether their relationship was personal or
>   professional."
>
> Judge Zudan considered, then said, "Overruled. The prosecution may
>   continue."
>
> Tahiri felt heat rising in her cheeks, but kept her face calm. "So,
>   would it be accurate to say that you and Jacen Solo were *lovers*?"
>   Dekkon continued.
>
> **"We were involved," Tahiri said bluntly. "Love had nothing to do with
>   it."**
>
> "So we may assume that you were *physically*—"
>
> "Objection!" Eramuth said again. His whiskers bristled, and he was the
>   very image of wounded propriety. "Further questioning along this line
>   verges on the salacious. A relationship has been established. No one
>   here needs to know details. This is a trial, not a holodrama."

The judge agrees with the defender (Eramuth) and the trial moves on to other topics. But now I'm curious. This exchange would seem to indicate that Tahiri and Jacen had a sexual relationship... yet at no time during the "Legacy of the Force" story arc was that mentioned or even hinted at. Solo was still in love with Tenel Ka at that time, and Tahiri was still in love with Anakin Solo despite his death.

**Did Tahiri have a sexual relation with Jacen Solo, or am I simply reading this exchange incorrectly?**

Comment: That's how I read the exchange, though that's my opinion, not an acceptable answer.

Comment: We need to remember that a lot of what Jacen was doing at this time was all about controlling those around him. Tahiri was infatuated with him, but more due to him getting her closer to Anakin Solo through the Flow-Walking